# Specialized constructor for template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor

Suppose that there are 3 classses:

```
template <typename T>
class X;


template <typename T>
class Y;


template <typename T>
class Z;
```

I wish to define a constructor for `X` which takes an object reference of type `Z<T>` and returns an object of type `X<Y<T>>`. Is this possible with a single template definition?

```
template <typename T>
X<Y<T>>::X(Z<T>) {
  // logic to map Z<T> to Y<T> and pass it on for object creation.
}
```

I guess there will be significant side-effects if I use two template definitions for defining the constructor.

Comment: Constructors don't return anything.

Comment: A constructor does not return anything, not even `void`. How do you want to use it?

Comment: What I mean to say is that it should create an object of type `X<Y<T>>`.
On a different note, the constructors create a local copy of the object and hand over the reference to it, don't they? If used with new, this object is shifted to main memory. That's what I thought happened in the background. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @n.m. I have added more details to the question in the last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
template <class T>
class Z;

template <class T>
class Y;

template <class T>
class X
{
    X(Z&);
};

template<class T>
X<Y<T>> MakeX(Z<T>& z)
{
    return X<Y<T>>(z);
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is the exact tranformation I have in mind. Why do I have to name it MakeX? Why not something like this?

`template <typename T> X<Y<T>>::X(Z<T>)`

Comment: @ibp73 In order to have something like that, you need to specialize the entire `X` template for `Y<T>`. That is, you would have to write `template <typename T> class X<Y<T>> { ...; X(Z<T>) { ... } ... }'`.

Comment: `X(Z&);` should be `X(Z<T>&);`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you can accomplish what you want to using a single template class. However, you can use template specialization to accomplish what you are looking for.

Here's a minimal definition of such a class.

```
template <typename T> class X
{
};

template <typename T> class Y
{
};

template <typename T> class Z
{
};

template <typename T> class X<Y<T> >
{
   public:
      X(Z<T> z) {}
};


int main()
{
   Z<int> z;
   X<Y<int> > x(z);
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu
That is okay. But I do not want to explicitly define `class X<Y<T>>` . Why can't I add a simple constructor like?

`template <typename T> X<Y<T>>::X(Z<T>)`

Comment: @ibp73 You cannot define a constructor for `X<Y<T>>` under the definition of `X<T>`.

Comment: @R Sahu This is strange. Do I need to re-write all the member functions already defined for `X<T>` in the definition of `X<Y<T>>` again?

Comment: @ibp73 That will be necessary, but I can see why that will be a problem. The other alternative is to use an external function, as was suggested by Neil Kirk.

Answer (score 1):

Direct way to achieve this:

```
template <typename T>
class Y{};

template <typename T>
class Z{};

template <typename T>
class X
{
    template <typename U>
    X(U){}
};

template <typename T>
template <>
X<Y<T>>::X(Z<T>){}
```

Unfortunately, this code is not standard-compliant.

If you *really* don't want to use a helper function ([**@Neil Kirk**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2068573/neil-kirk)'s [variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890675/specialized-constructor-for-template-class/22890734#22890734)) or specialize a whole class ([**@R Sahu**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu)'s [variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890675/specialized-constructor-for-template-class/22890901#22890901)) you may try the following variant using `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct template_traits;

template
    <
        template <typename>
        class C,
        typename A
    >
struct template_traits<C<A>>
{
    using argument_type = A;
};

template
    <
        typename T,
        template <typename>
        class C
    >
struct is_instantiation_of : std::false_type{};

template
    <
        typename A,
        template <typename>
        class C
    >
struct is_instantiation_of<C<A>, C> : std::true_type{};


template <typename T>
class Y{};

template <typename T>
class Z{};

template <typename T>
class X
{
public:

    X(){}

    template
        <
            typename U = T,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<is_instantiation_of<U, Y>::value>::type
        >
    X(Z<typename template_traits<U>::argument_type>& z){}

};
```

Example of using:

```
Y<int> y_i;
Y<char> y_c;
Z<int> z_i;
Z<char> z_c;

X<int> x; // compiles
X<Y<int>> x1(z_i); // compiles
X<Y<int>> x2(z_c); // doesn't compile
X<Z<int>> x3(y_i); // doesn't compile
X<Z<int>> x4(y_c); // doesn't compile
```

Comment: I really liked the first idea that you suggested even though there were compliance issue. I tried the exact same code but the following error got thrown during compilation. I tried it with the C++11 standard as well.

`test_template2.cc:16:10: error: nested name specifier 'X<Y<T> >::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
X<Y<T>>::X(Z<T>){}`

Comment: @ibp73 In my first code example I only tried to formulate what you wanted to do. Both in C++03 and C++11 you can't to do this. So your compiler is right. The simple explanation is that the `template` keyword with empty template parameters list `<>` can not follow the one with non-empty list `<typename T>`. More complex explanation is that you can't partially specialize template functions and template class function members.